# Implementar un iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, iframe

Me ocupa lo siguiente
estoy intentando hacer un iframe en un sitio diferente al dominio en cuestion el iframe que estoy tratando de ejecutar es con la idea de que contenga la siguiente web http://www.movilnet.com.ve/conweb/ pero no logro hacerlo funcionar estoy intentando con el siguiente codigo:

```html
    <iframe width="480" height="305" margin="auto" src="http://www.movilnet.com.ve/conweb/" style="border:none" scrolling=no frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
```

Cualquier alternativa me puede servir, php, javascript o jquery

Comment: me temo a que no se puede hacer eso, a esperar mas respuestas

Comment: desde https no podes cargar http

Comment: Si correcto ese es el error @aloMalbarez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer eso debes de borrar la cabecera `X-Frame-Options` de la petición HTTP y se permitirá el acceso a cualquier dominio externo al tuyo desde tu propia web.

Si estás usando HTTPS en tu servidor y obligas a usar HTTPS redireccionando, bloqueando tráfico o similar, tendrás que tener en cuenta este caso en concreto para tratarlo.

Answer (score -2):

Vas a tener que implementar en las dos webs ssl https o en las dos http.
Lo unico que te recomiendo es:

```
<a href="http://www.movilnet.com.ve/conweb/" target="_blank">Realizar Recarga</a>
```

Realizar Recarga

Saludos

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta.

Comment: Al usuario le sirvio por que venis a decir vos que no no es correcta?
, es una posible solucion sin implementar Iframe ya que no va a poder por su certificado SSL.

Comment: @Jota Por favor cuando digas que algo es incorrecto, aclara el porque es incorrecto. Si no soluciona el problema de ninguna forma, aclaralo tambien.

Comment: Gracias, a ciencia cierta ambas respuestas son correctas eso es lo bueno de la informatica, para obtener un mismo resultado se pueden utilizar varias opciones de solución..! de hecho la respuesta de @JeffFernando la marque como útil pero es algo que ya lo tengo implementado en mi sitio web, pero las solución que abajo marque como aceptada creo que técnicamente da respuesta a mi interrogante, pero agradezco a todos por tomarse su tiempo y en querer ayudar, se les aprecia mucho..!!!